# CSS positioning during scroll event unresponsive and jittery on OSX Safari (works in Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, safari

I have a sticky border on my website, and during the window's scroll event I update it to follow the window when the user scrolls.

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
}
.container {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    $('.fixed').css({top: $(window).scrollTop()});   
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xt8c00yq/

I know scroll events are unreliable and unresponsive on mobile browsers, so I have already disabled it for devices. However, it seems to be laggy and jittery on the desktop version of Safari as well. It works fine on both Chrome and Firefox. Test the demo on both browsers to see for yourselves.

Are there any known hacks to make it update smoothly on Safari as well?

(position:fixed is not an option as it needs to flow in response to an unfixed sibling css transition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap into hardware accelerated rendering with `translate3d`.

```
$(window).scroll( function() {

    scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();   

    $('.fixed').css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled + 'px,0)',
        '-moz-transform'    : 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled + 'px,0)',
        '-ms-transform'     : 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled + 'px,0)',
        '-o-transform'      : 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled + 'px,0)',
        'transform'         : 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled + 'px,0)'
    });

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me, neither on the demo or on my website. But thanks. I've seen this solution work in similar situations, so I'm sure it'll help someone.

Comment: @haspaker Safari 7.1.6 and the jsfiddle you posted is super jittery. Replaced with my code runs smooth as butter. Did you remember to "Run" the code on jsfiddle after updating and clear your cache when testing on your site? [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xt8c00yq/1/)

Comment: Safari 8.0.6 here. Sorry, I did not test the demo enough to see the improvement (quit as soon as I saw jittering). Yeah, replacing it with your code in the demo is a huge improvement, but it still jitters quite often (too much to look good on the website). On the website for some reason I couldn't see any improvement at all (tested multiple times with slight variations, and cleared the cache between each time).

Comment: [Here's the updated jsfiddle that I ran.](https://jsfiddle.net/467uq21v/) And [here's a gif showing the jittering](http://imgur.com/SwFLsqw) even on the improved version. If the element is not required to be 100% jitter-free your solution works great, but even a little jitter just looks too strange in my scenario. I just wish Safari would fix this like Chrome and Firefox have done. :(

Comment: @haspaker You might want to debug your Safari because I have to scroll something fierce to get any jitter. Try using `$(window).on('scroll mousewheel', function () {` to track both scroll and mousewheel.